# Update Excel header and footer on several rows with Office Scripts

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have created an Office script that works fine.
The best part is that I can call on the script from Power Automate, get information from a Sharepoint Online document properties and paste it in the Header and Footer in an Excel file.

The Office script looks like this:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, Title: string, EID: string, ApprovedBy: string, ModifiedBy: string, Publisher: string, EVersion: string) {
    
        var sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
    
        for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
            const sheet = sheets[i];
            const pagelayout = sheet.getPageLayout();
            const headerFooter = pagelayout.getHeadersFooters()
            const defaultForPages = headerFooter.getDefaultForAllPages()
    
            defaultForPages.setLeftHeader(Title)
            defaultForPages.setCenterHeader(EID)
            defaultForPages.setRightHeader(EVersion)
            defaultForPages.setLeftFooter(ModifiedBy)
            defaultForPages.setCenterFooter(ApprovedBy)
            defaultForPages.setRightFooter(Publisher)
    
        }
    }
```

[image]

What I am looking for is how to add two rows of information in the same section in the footer, for example ApprovedBy AND Publisher in the RightFooter.

ApprovedBy "Me"
Publisher "Someone Else"

Comment: The formatting of the question does not look like I expected :-)

Comment: I solved it in Power Automate by using ENTER :-) and added two rows in the same field with meta data from the Get File Properties in the Run script from SharePoint Library block

Answer (score 1):

- Office Script can update the content in footer and header.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const pagelayout = sheet.getPageLayout();
    const headerFooter = pagelayout.getHeadersFooters()
    const defaultForPages = headerFooter.getDefaultForAllPages()
    const line1 = "Approved By:"
    const line2 = "Publisher:"
    let rightFooter = defaultForPages.getRightFooter();
    rightFooter += '\n' + line1 + '\n' + line2
    defaultForPages.setRightFooter(rightFooter)
}
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [getRightFooter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.headerfooter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-headerfooter-setrightfooter-member(1))

> [setRightFooter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.headerfooter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-headerfooter-setrightfooter-member(1))

[image]